# How to remove filter when clicking on a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show many phone numbers on page, and each of them are initially displayed as "short" phone.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-click="showFull()">{{phone1 | short}}</div>
  <div ng-click="showFull()">{{phone2 | short}}</div>
  <div ng-click="showFull()">{{phone3 | short}}</div>
  <div ng-click="showFull()">{{phone4 | short}}</div>
  <div ng-click="showFull()">{{phone5 | short}}</div>
</div>
```

Corresponding angularjs code:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.filter("short", function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.toString().substring(0,3) +"...";
  };
})
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.phone1 = 1111111;
  $scope.phone2 = 2222222;
  $scope.phone3 = 3333333;
  $scope.phone4 = 4444444;
  $scope.phone5 = 5555555;

  $scope.showFull = function() {
    ???
  }
});
```

You can see I don't know how to define the `showFull` method.

How to define it, or give any other simple solutions(e.g. write a directive)?

PS: here is a working demo: http://jsbin.com/gobohuwa/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a directive.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dE9s7/4/)

Here's the link function that will apply the `shortFilter` depending on toggle state of the div. I also implemented a `scope.$watch`function so that changes to the model will still be applied to the directive. It's a rough code and I'm not sure with the performance though.

```
function link(scope, element) {
    var isFilterLabel = true;

    scope.$watch("model", function() {
        updateText();
    });

    element.on('click', function(event) {
        isFilterLabel = !isFilterLabel;
        updateText();
    });

    var updateText = function() {
        console.log(scope.model);
        var text = isFilterLabel ? shortFilter(scope.model) : scope.model;
        element.text(text);  
    }
}
```